# Nothing is printing out in the console, I thought I called it but I guess not and now I am stuck

Tags: python

original question reformated as code sample.

```
def animals(ani1, ani2, ani3):
    if ani1 == ani2 or ani1 == ani3:
        return "Match was Found"
    elif ani2 == ani1 or ani2 == ani3:
        return "Match was Found"
    elif ani3 == ani2 or ani3 == ani1:
        return "Match was Found"
    else:
        return "No Match Found"
    print(animals("dogs", "dogs", "cats"))
```

Comment: That last line shouldn't be indented - that makes it part of the `animals` function, so it will never be executed.

Comment: You need to un-indent your `print(animals(...` line otherwise it is being called inside the `animals` method itself

Comment: No need to include an image of your code, thanks, text is better.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you indent `print(animals("dogs", "dogs", "cats"))` line also in the function so it is not execute until you call the function.

Remove indent from the last line then it will work fine.

```py
def animals(ani1, ani2, ani3):

 if ani1 == ani2 or ani1 == ani3:

     return "Match was Found"
 elif ani2 == ani1 or ani2 == ani3:

     return "Match was Found"
 elif ani3 == ani2 or ani3 == ani1:

     return "Match was Found"
 else:

     return "No Match Found"

print(animals("dogs", "dogs", "cats"))
```

Comment: Worth adding that Python is usually indented with 4 spaces ([PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation)) because an indentation difference of 1 space is quite subtle and easy to overlook.

Comment: Yeah, if you will not take a closer look you can't find out.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is inside of the function. Move it outside of the function (remove the indentation) and it will work.